# GAS HTMLService: Pushing variables with createTemplateFromFile in file included in template

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I use CreateTemplateFromFile and push a variable inside my template. My template file is including another file, but I'm not able to push this variable in the second file embedded.

Here below what I've tried:

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?!= include('header'); ?>
    <?!= include('style'); ?>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>

<?!= include('script'); ?>

</html>
```

the script part of the index.html in a separate file:

```html
<script>
  function getData() {
    $("#loadingMessage").html('Loading');
    console.log('myContent:', <?= data ?>);
    ...
  }
</script>
```

The doGet part of the Google apps script code:

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
template.data = myContent;

return template.evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

the variable is correctly pushed in index.html but not reach the script part.
Any idea ? Maybe to include the script file as a template also ?

Comment: Do you want to push data from the .gs part into the .js part or the opposite?

Comment: Hi, I want to push already prepared data from gs to js to avoid having complex js code in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to pass variables between Apps Script and Javascript.

Google Apps Script features the method [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) that can be called from the JS part of a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). The methods allows to pass parameters to an Apps Script function and to assign the return value of the GAS function back to a JS function.

**Sample:**

> .gs file

```
function doGet() {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function myContent(input) {
  var myContent="foo"+input;
  return myContent;
}
```

> HTML/js file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="getData()">
    <script>
      function getData() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(proceedData).myContent("bar");
       ...
     }
      function proccedData(returnValue) {
        var data  = returnValue;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### If you want to use scriptlets

The [documentation specifies](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates):

- Remember, however, that because template code executes before the page is served to the user, these techniques can only feed initial content to a page. To access Apps Script data from a page interactively, use the google.script.run API instead.
- Because scriptlet code executes before the page is served, it can only run once per page; unlike client-side JavaScript or Apps Script functions that you call through google.script.run, scriptlets can't execute again after the page loads.^
- scriptlets can call functions defined in other code files, reference **global variables**, or use any of the Apps Script APIs.

In your case, if you want to use scriptlets, you either have to call a function or make your variable `data`global, e.g.:

```
//global variable
var data=myContent;

function doGet() {
  var temp=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html");
  return temp.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

> Also keep in mind:

- Templates can be challenging to debug because the code you write is not executed directly; instead, the server transforms your template into code, then executes that resulting code.

Comment: What is the added value of using google.script.run in your example compared to pushing the value through the templating system of HtmlService? I think it could work in my specific case but would need to mix both solutions.

Comment: I updated my answer mentioning the restrictions of using scriptlets and giving a modification suggestion if you want to use them anyway.

Comment: Many thanks Ziganotschka for your time and explanations. Just tested your proposal on my code and works very well! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped!